# Creating a month variable in R by separating '03' from '20150315'

Tags: r

I have my dates formatted as '20150315' for the one year (2015) but now I want to separate my data into categories for the 12 months by creating another variable called Month. How could I do this in R?

Comment: Use substr:   substr(x = '20150320', start = 5, stop = 6)

Comment: @EugenR Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option with `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
df$Month <- month(ymd(df$Date))
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Date='20150315')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `base R` functions `format()` and `as.Date()`. I have used dummy data `df`:

```
#Data
df <- data.frame(Date='20150315',stringsAsFactors = F)
#Format
df$Month <- format(as.Date(df$Date,'%Y%m%d'),'%m')
```

Output:

```
df
      Date Month
1 20150315    03
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @Lily Always a pleasure :)